# How to properly decompile c# dlls for debugging with Visual Studio 2022 and .net 4.8

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-debugging

In Virual Studio 2022 I have a c# .net 4.8 project that references a dll for which I do not have the source code.

I want to debug through the decompiled dll code. The dll has a corresponding .pdb file included in the same directory.

Here my Debug settings:
[image]

With F12 I can view decompiled code. However, when I start debugging (F5) and try to step in
(F11) into the dll, Visual Studio seams to debug a different version of the code. For example, Visual studio moves the debugging cursor through comments (screenshot below)...

[image]

Is there anything that I am missing in my setup? Or is the .pdb outdated..? How can I set up visual studio to decompile and properly debug through the dll?

Comment: This does indeed suggest a mismatch between the assembly and the pdb.

Comment: Yes, the PDB and DLL are definitely out of sync.

Comment: Decompiled code cannot provide comments.  This *might* be a bug where it generated the comments from the Intellisense .xml file, if you see that file then remove it.  Remove the .pdb file next.  Tick "Require source files to exactly match" so you can tell that you're looking at an outdated source file.

Comment: @anar Hi, you can take a look at my answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your situation:

[image]

**Reasons for this situation: the decompiled code does not match the original code, or the pdb file does not match the source file version.**

Mechanism：

Because for C#, pdb records mainly information such as line numbers (if it is cpp, there will be source code information in pdb, which is different), and because the source file on your side is different from what it should be, it will "step into" a place that you "think" is completely wrong when you press f11, but actually it already go to the right place (I mean, it really should go to that line if you press f11 if the source file matches).

The key to your problem is to ensure the consistency of the three files: source file, dll and pdb.

You can use a tool like dotpeek to decompile the C# dll file into a project(you can use this tool to export dll to be a totally new project/solution), and then you can build this new project. In this case, you can ensure that the source files, dll and pdb in this new project are consistent . Have your test project refer to the dll in this decompiled project so you won't run into problems.

It should be noted that **the decompilation operation cannot guarantee that the decompilation code is 100% the same as the source code. It is inevitable that the code obtained in this way will be somewhat different from the source code.**

By the way, as hans mentioned, there is a feature named 'Require source files that exactly match the original version':

[image]

This is the official document:

[Require source files that exactly match the original version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/debuggers/troubleshooting-breakpoints#-the-current-source-code-is-different-from-the-version-built-into)

You need to turn on this feature(This is the default turn-on setting on my side.).

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed answer! Is there a standard way to debug within dlls in Visual studio? As fas as I know in java this is possible because you can include the sources into the .jar during compilation.

Comment: @anarchipur The java jar package and dll you mentioned are different concepts. The former is similar to the nupkg package of .net. They are also in the form of a compressed package. The dll is more similar to the .class file under the concept of java. They are a binary document. Some pdbs, especially those of some official packages, contain Source Link information. This allows us to download the code from a remote repo if there is no corresponding version of the code when we try to debug. As far as I know, dll does not have the mechanism you mentioned to directly entrain source code files.

Comment: @anarchipur 
I think you need to have a good understanding of the role of pdb in C# projects. The debugging of C# code in VS is completely based on this pdb technology. After understanding it, you can understand how to debug C# related things in VS: [Specify symbol (.pdb) and source files in the Visual Studio debugger (C#, C++, Visual Basic, F#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2022) After understand pdb, I think you could know what is the standard way to debug dll. :)