# How to interact with GitVersion init in Visual Studio Package Manager Console

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, gitversion

When using GitVersion you interact by using `gitversion init` to access the executable available via NuGet.

However it looks like the package manager console does not register keypresses when running a command. The navigation works by numbers (eg: 2) Run wizard)

How do you interact with the number menu `gitversion init` in Visual Studio 2022??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio, certain interactive console applications might not behave as expected due to the limitations of the console. The Package Manager Console is designed primarily for NuGet operations and PowerShell scripts, so it doesn't handle interactive applications in the same way a standard terminal or command prompt would.

I think what you need is terminal window:

[image]

It can achieve your requirement:

[image]

**Notice: You need to add the tool path to the system environment variable, after that, you will be able to use the tool in the terminal window.**

I create a folder named 'gitversion_test' in 'C:\Users\Administrator.nuget\packages', so the path is 'C:\Users\Administrator.nuget\packages\gitversion_test', and then extract package content to this path(download [the package here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GitVersion.CommandLine), and rename it to xxx.zip, after that you could extract the content).

After the above step, configure path to system environment variable:

[image]

Detailed configuration steps please refer to this:

[How to properly decompile c# dlls for debugging with Visual Studio 2022 and .net 4.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77046309/how-to-properly-decompile-c-sharp-dlls-for-debugging-with-visual-studio-2022-and/77049518#77049518)

You need to close VS and then reopen it, then the new VS instance could be able to use the tool in terminal.

Comment: I was hoping not to rely on pc settings for this to keep portability nuget offers.... but this will work